# Serialize only superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, serialization

I have the following classes:

```
class A implements Serializable {
  String field1;
  String field2;
  // a lot more fields here...
}

class B extends A {
  int someOtherField;
}
```

where `B` is my class and `A` is in a package I don't own. In my environment, an object of class `B` is serialized and will later be deserialized in a different environment, where only class `A` is in the classpath and not class `B`, thus an error will occur, that class `B` is not found.

To solve this problem, I could add a copy constructor to `A` as follows and instead of serializing an object `b`, I would serialize `new A(b)`:

```
A(A other) {
  this.field1 = other.field1;
  this.field1 = other.field1;
  // and so on
}
```

My problem now is that I can only change `B`, but not `A`.
So, is there any way I can serialize a `B` and deserialize it as an `A` without access to the source code of `A`?

Comment: Why do you need to be able to change `A` to make a "copy constructor"? Just add an `A toA()` method to `B`.

Comment: oh well... I don't know how I didn't think of this myself... I feel embarrassed for asking this question. But thanks for your help.

Comment: @AndyTurner Wouldn't the object constructed using B still throw a `ClassNotFoundException` on the second system, since the serialization definition contains B?

Comment: @RajeevSreedharan if you create a `new A` in that method... no.